# Plot only the last 2 connected swing high/low (Repainting Indicator)

Tags: pine-script

I coded an indicator that plot the highest high (and lowest lows) whenever a moving average cross happens.

The code below works great but there is one issue with it, it's keeping the previous highs that were broken after the cross.

I would like the lines to be only connected from one lowest lows point and one highest high point since the crosses like a zig zag indicator.

The picture below explain that better, the green line is what the indicator plots. The black line is what it should be plotting instead.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2dlO.jpg

Is there any work around to solve this issue? Thank you

```
//@version=4
study(title="MA Cross", overlay=true, max_bars_back=3000)

MA1 = sma(close, 20)
MA2 = sma(close, 100)

Highest(src, len) =>
    max = high
    for i = 1 to len
        if src[i] > max
            max := src[i]
    max

Lowest(src, len) =>
    min = src[0]
    for i = 1 to len
        if src[i] < min
            min := src[i]
    min


trend = 0
trend := na(trend[1]) ? 1 : trend[1]

LL = 0.0
HH = 0.0

HH := Highest(high, barssince(cross(MA1, MA2)))
LL := Lowest(low, barssince(cross(MA1, MA2)))

HighLow = 0.0

recent = 0

HL = 0.0

if(MA1 > MA2)

    recent := 1

    for i = 1 to 200
        if(MA1[i] < MA2[i])
            break

        if(high < high[i])
            recent := -1
            break

    HL := na
    if(recent < 0)
        HighLow := na

    else        
        HighLow := high
        HL := high


else
    recent := 1
    HL := na
    for i = 1 to 200
        if(MA1[i] > MA2[i])
            break

        if(low > low[i])
            recent := -1
            break

    if(recent < 0)
        HighLow := na

    else        
        HighLow := low
        HL := low


plot(series= HighLow, color = color.green, linewidth=3)
plot(series=MA1, color = color.aqua, linewidth=1)
plot(series=MA2, color = color.orange, linewidth=1)
```

Comment: It's based on zigzag indicator and the way zigzag works repaints, so why don't you try to create a harmonic pattern indicator instead of use zigzag?

Comment: Because the highest highs and the lowest lows between every MA cross is my objective. I am trying to make the indicator plot the lines between the crosses without keeping the previous broken highs/lows there.

Comment: Forget Ma crossover it's not the best way to enter a trade

Comment: Try using `line` but I cannot guarantee a repaint-less solution. Have a look at [this](https://www.tradingview.com/script/prH14cfo-Trend-Direction-Helper-ZigZag-and-S-R-and-HH-LL-labels/).

Comment: Thanks Baris, the line feature in pine script would work perfectly. The only issue I found with the lines is the chart cannot handle more than 50-55 lines on the chart.

Comment: I guess there is `line.delete` for that. Also, [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#zig-zag) might be easier to understand than the other one.

Comment: Yes I know how to code the same indicator with the lines. They are inconvenient because of the chart resource limits especially since the lines wouldn't be the only objects drawn on the chart for this indicator. I will put labels on the swings as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, this won't plot lines on all the dataset because it uses `line.new()`. Still, in case it can be useful:

```
//@version=4
study(title="MA Cross", overlay=true, max_bars_back=3000)

MA1 = sma(close, 20)
MA2 = sma(close, 100)

// Highest/lowest hi/lo during up/dn trend.
var hi = 0.
var lo = 10e20
// Bar index of highest/lowest hi/lo.
var hiBar = 0
var loBar = 0
// Crosses.
crossUp = crossover(MA1, MA2)
crossDn = crossunder(MA1, MA2)
upTrend = MA1 > MA2

// Draw line in past when a cross occurs.
if crossUp or crossDn
    line.new(bar_index[bar_index - hiBar], high[bar_index - hiBar], bar_index[bar_index - loBar], low[bar_index - loBar], xloc.bar_index, extend.none, color.black)

// Reset hi/lo and bar index on crosses.
if crossUp
    hi := high
    hiBar := bar_index
else
    if crossDn
        lo := low
        loBar := bar_index

// Update higher/lower hi/lo during trend.
if upTrend and high > hi
    hi := high
    hiBar := bar_index
else
    if not upTrend and low < lo
        lo := low
        loBar := bar_index

plot(series=MA1, color = color.aqua, linewidth=1)
plot(series=MA2, color = color.orange, linewidth=1)

// Debugging.        
// plot(hi, "High", color.green, 1, plot.style_circles)
// plot(lo, "Low", color.red, 1, plot.style_circles)
// plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index", "", location.top)
// plotchar(hiBar, "hiBar", "", location.top, color = color.green)
// plotchar(loBar, "loBar", "", location.top, color = color.red)
// bgcolor(upTrend ? color.green : color.red)
```

[image]